# Azure Web app for containers to on-premises connection

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, containers, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-web-app-for-containers

Currently i'm hosting an API in an azure Web App for Containers App Service. Additionally, I have a logging database hosted on an on-premises service which can't be accessed publicly.

For accessing the on-premises service it is possible to create a hybrid connection; however this feature is not available through the Azure portal when using Web App for Containers as opposed to when using just a Web App.

Is it possible to create this Hybrid Connection programmatically or through the CLI?

Are there other methods of connecting to on-premises resources through azure?

The API is using ASP.NET Core.

I have been looking into the Microsoft.Azure.Relay package, but I seem to be unable to actually reach my on-premises endpoint through the samples supplied by the package.

**Edit:**

I have verified that i can make the Hybrid Connection using a Web App. To do this i have downloaded the Hybrid Connection Manager, installed it on the on-premises network and checked that an application can make HTTP calls to the endpoint at the end of the Hybrid Connection.

All of this is done through the azure portal by going into my Web App, then navigating to Networking, configuring Hybrid Connections and creating a Hybrid Connection, and connecting to the new Hybrid Connection through the Hybrid Connection Manager.

What i'm not capable of is doing the same for my Web App for Containers, as Networking is not a supported tap (yet?). Therefore, i'm looking for a programmatical way of doing this either through the CLI or in the sourcecode.

Comment: service bus relay would require either a listener/service which can talk in http and websockets or  a .net based wcf service endpoint on premises. if you have either of those you can get this going.

Comment: I have added some details to the original question, but basically, i have verified that i can make hybrid connections with normal Web Apps. This was doing by creating a listener on the on-premises network and connecting to a Hybrid Connection.